# Convert ASCII to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which contains ASCII concated numbers, anyway to convert it to `string(text)`?
For example I have `114097102097101108` in one column and I want the next column to be 'rafael' (converted from ASCII to text).
Link to convert `http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/`.

Comment: Hint: `SELECT CHAR(114) + CHAR(097) + CHAR(102) + CHAR(097) + CHAR(101) + CHAR(108)`

Comment: Surprisingly hard to do in T-SQL because the sub-task of splitting a string in parts of three characters is hard. Do you really, literally, need this exact conversion, or is this some sort of "obfuscation" feature? A string can be easily converted into a hexstring representation of its code points (`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'rafael'), 2)`) and vice versa, but it all depends on what you need this for.

Comment: Are all of the ascii characters 3 digits in length when concatenated? i.e. `097` not `097`? It seems that way from your example, but it's probably worth specifying for clarity

Comment: Jeroen Mostert and Diado thanks for your help, It's every time a different single word in the column needed to be translated from ascii to string, one string of ascii numbers that has to be translated to text, first column is 114097102097101108 and next column has to the result of rafael, 2 ed row is 106097109101115 and result in 2ed column is 'james' and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to get this done. This will handle strings up to 30K chars long and convert them into 10k strings.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertASCIItoCHAR(
    @String varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( LEN(@String)/3) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT ( SELECT CHAR(SUBSTRING( @String, n*3+1, 3))
        FROM cteTally
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS String
```

Now the only thing that you need to do is call the function.

```
SELECT c.String
FROM dbo.ConvertASCIItoCHAR( '114097102097101108') c
```

or

```
SELECT c.String
FROM SomeTable st
CROSS APPLY dbo.ConvertASCIItoCHAR( st.SomeString) c
```

Comment: "This will handle strings up to 30K" - no, this will handle strings up to 8K long, and return a string up to 2666 chars long.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I forgot to copy the edited code using varchar(max). Thank you for noticing.

Comment: Thank you both Zohar and Luis

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select '0' + convert(varchar(max), ascii(left(col, 1))) as rafael, stuff(col, 1, 1, '') as rest, 1 as lev, id, col
      from t
      union all
      select rafael + ' 0' + convert(varchar(max), ascii(left(rest, 1))), stuff(rest, 1, 1, ''), lev + 1, id, col
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select top (1) with ties id, col, rafael
from cte
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by lev desc);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25ec3b448e0623ba3074a36ce3de653b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Much appreciated Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method using a tally table, if you have much larger strings:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP 8000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4),
Parts AS(
    SELECT V.CatNum,
           T.I
    FROM (VALUES('114097102097101108'))V(CatNum)
         JOIN Tally T ON LEN(V.CatNum) >= T.I
    WHERE T.I % 3 = 0)
SELECT V.CatNum,
       (SELECT CHAR(SUBSTRING(P.CatNum,LAG(P.I,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY P.I)+1,3))
        FROM Parts P
        WHERE P.CatNum = V.CatNum
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(8000)') AS NewString
FROM (VALUES('114097102097101108'))V(CatNum)
```

Comment: If one of these answers sovled the problem for you, @refaelo1979, you should mark it as the solution